# Swift UiAlertController after another at runtime

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I found some solutions solving the problem to show more than one UIAlertController but they aren't working for me. While starting the app it could be possible that more than one alert needs to be shown. So when I call the showAlert() function I do not know if there will be more alerts. With rootViewController.presentViewController(..) it's only possible to show one and the others will be ignored. So what I need to do is to check if one alert is presented otherwise queue the alert and after closing the first alert check if there are more alerts to show. My idea was to solve this with NSOperation and NSOperationQueue, saying that just one Operation can be executed in time. Something like this:

```
var alertQueue : NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()    

func showAlert(alertController: UIAlertController) {
    alertQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    alertQueue.addOperation(NSOperationAlert(alertController: alertController))
}
```

The NSOperation:

```
class NSOperationAlert: NSOperation {

    let aController : UIAlertController

    init(alertController : UIAlertController) {
        aController = alertController
    }

    override func start() { 
        AppRouter.sharedInstance.window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(aController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

But obviously something is missing. I don't know exactly how to solve that the next queued alert is shown after the other alert isn't shown anymore. In other words how do I know that the currently presented Alert is "finished" without adding a handler to each button and tell this my alertQueue to execute the next alert if there is one.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why don't you want to add handler to each button? It seems like a way to do it. Unless there is some system notification you can subscribe for that is posted when a popover window closes

Comment: I don't want to add a handler because there are a lot of possible alerts which I would need to change. My hope was that I could handle this with just adding the alert to a (NSOperation)queue that knows if the first alert in it was closed.

Comment: How about subclassing the alert controller and putting this into view did disappear method? Subclassing the alert action might work as well.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. I ended up with adding a handler to each button. In contrast to what I wanted to do, but it seems to be the best way.